# how do i check if a discord message contains a string

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i am trying to make a discord bot with discord,.py and i want the bot to say something when someone sends a message that contains a certain string. this is what i want to happen

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if 'i' in msg:
        channel = client.get_channel("742261026686500896")
        await channel.send("i")
```

i get this error

```
TypeError: argument of type 'Message' is not iterable
```

how would i go about doing this?

Comment: `msg` is an object with several attributes. The text portion is found in `msg.content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if 'i' in msg:
        channel = client.get_channel("742261026686500896")
        await channel.send("i")
```

The discord `Message` is an uniterable **object** (the reason you are getting the error). You are not accessing the information properly. The `Message` object contains information on the other, channel, etc.
You can check the docs on this topic, [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#message).
To access the content of the message, you should use `msg.content`.
Then, you can run the test on that. Example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if 'i' in msg.conent:
        channel = client.get_channel("742261026686500896")
        await channel.send("i")
```

Comment: It would be nice if you also showed the solution

Comment: @Kafels Added. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`msg` is an object with several attributes. The text portion is found in `msg.content`. Try this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if 'i' in msg.content:
        channel = client.get_channel("742261026686500896")
        await channel.send("i")
```